# Access=stream is throwing a Fortran runtime error

Tags: fortran

I have a piece of code that works on my laptop but not on our Linux cluster. It's pretty straight forward.

```
open(11,file=trim(openfile),form='unformatted',access='STREAM')
```

throws a runtime error:

```
Fortran runtime error: Bad ACCESS parameter in OPEN statement
```

What is happening?

gcc was build as:

```
gfortran -v Using built-in specs. Target: x86_64-redhat-linux 
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man 
--infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix 
--enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit 
--disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile 
--enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada 
--enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin 
--with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre 
--with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux 
Thread model: posix gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)
```

Comment: STREAM access is a Fortran 2003 feature.  Your version of gfortran is too old for this.

Comment: I tried 4.1.2 on my laptop and it's works there.  I only see issues on the cluster when i try to run it in my shell.

Comment: Stream IO was first available in gfortran in version 4.2.0 - https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2006-08/msg00197.html

Comment: 4.1.2 is from Feb 2007 (https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html).  I wouldn't use a version of gfortran earlier than 4.4, and preferably newer. There have been many improvements.